# Details of Syscall.RawSyscall() & Syscall.Syscall() in Go?

Tags: unix, assembly, operating-system, go, system-calls

I'm reading source code in package `syscall` now, and met some problems:

Since I'm totally a noob of `syscall` and `assembly`, so don't hesitate to share anything you know about it :)

First about func `RawSyscall(trap, a1, a2, a3 uintptr) (r1, r2 uintptr, err Errno)` : what does its parameter `trap, a1, a2, a3` & return value `r1 r2` means? I've searched documents and site but seems lack of description about this.

Second, since I'm using `darwin/amd64` I searched source code and find it here:
http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s?h=RawSyscall

Seems it's written by assemble(which I can't understand), can you explain what happened in line 61-80, and what's the meaning of `ok1:` part under line 76?

I also found some code in http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go , what does `zsyscall` mean in its filename?

What's the difference between `syscall` & `rawsyscall`?

How and when to use them if I want to write my own syscall function(Yes, os package gave many choices but there are still some situation it doesn't cover)?

So many noob questions, thanks for your patience to read and answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll share my reduced assembly knowledge with you:

```
61  TEXT ·RawSyscall(SB),7,$0
62      MOVQ    16(SP), DI
63      MOVQ    24(SP), SI
64      MOVQ    32(SP), DX
65      MOVQ    $0, R10
66      MOVQ    $0, R8
67      MOVQ    $0, R9
68      MOVQ    8(SP), AX   // syscall entry
69      ADDQ    $0x2000000, AX
70      SYSCALL
71      JCC ok1
72      MOVQ    $-1, 40(SP) // r1
73      MOVQ    $0, 48(SP)  // r2
74      MOVQ    AX, 56(SP)  // errno
75      RET
76  ok1:
77      MOVQ    AX, 40(SP)  // r1
78      MOVQ    DX, 48(SP)  // r2
79      MOVQ    $0, 56(SP)  // errno
80      RET
81
```

- Line 61 is the routine entry point
- Line 76 is a label called `ok1`
- Line 71 is a conditional jump to label `ok1`.

The short names you see on every line on the left side are called `mnemonics` and stand for assembly instructions:

- `MOVQ` means Move Quadword (64 bits of data).
- `ADDQ` is Add Quadword.
- `SYSCALL` is kinda obvious
- `JCC` is Jump if Condition (condition flag set by previous instruction)
- `RET` is return

On the right side of the mnemonics you'll find each instruction's arguments which are basically constants and [registers](http://tanmayonrun.blogspot.ch/2011/06/purposes-of-having-general-registers.html).

- `SP` is the Stack Pointer
- `AX` is the Accumulator
- `BX` is the Base register

each register can hold a certain amount of data. On 64 bit CPU architectures I believe it's in fact 64 bits per register.

The only difference between `Syscall` and `RawSyscall` is on line 14, 28 and 34 where `Syscall` will call `runtime·entersyscall(SB)` and `runtime·exitsyscall(SB)` whereas `RawSyscall` will not. I assume this means that `Syscall` notifies the runtime that it's switched to a blocking syscall operations and can yield CPU-time to another goroutine/thread whereas `RawSyscall` will just block.

Comment: Thank for quick reply, so is that mean programmers should use `Syscall` in non-blocking situations and `RawSyscall` in blocking situations?

Comment: I think user-level code should always use `Syscall` whereas `RawSyscall` exists for very specific situations.

Comment: RawSyscall exists for calling system calls you know do not block with slightly less overhead (since the runtime functions are not called).