# how do I clear the close-on-exec flag in go?

Tags: go

When os.OpenFile is called on Centos6, the O_CLOEXEC flag is set on the file handle.  I don't think it is possible to avoid the flag being set.  For example, the following call:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile( "lockfile", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR, 0666 )
```

looks like this in strace:

```
[pid  2928] open("lockfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3
```

syscall.CloseOnExec is provided to set the close-on-exec flag for a given file handle, but I can't find a corresponding function for clearing the close-on-exec flag.

How can I clear the close-on-exec flag for a file ?

Answer (score 4):

I found a hint in https://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/exec_linux.go:

```
        _, _, err1 = RawSyscall(SYS_FCNTL, uintptr(fd[i]), F_SETFD, 0)
        if err1 != 0 {
                goto childerror
        }
```

Elsewhere, I read I should use [Syscall rather than RawSyscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977988/details-of-syscall-rawsyscall-syscall-syscall-in-go), and so I rewrote this as:

```
    _, _, err = syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_FCNTL, f.Fd(), syscall.F_SETFD, 0)
    if err != syscall.Errno(0x0) {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```